# Use original column value after it is updated in the same UPDATE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In the following SQL statement (MySQL), I'm setting 3 columns.
In the last column I'm setting (PRT.stock_level) I need to subtract the original BOM.qty_planned BEFORE it is updated in the first column I'm setting. 
It seems that the last update already uses the CHANGED value, and I no longer have access to the original BOM.qty_planned value.

How can do this?

```
UPDATE mbom AS BOM, parts AS PRT
SET BOM.qty_planned = GREATEST(0, BOM.qty_planned - PRT.stock_level), 
    BOM.qty_available = GREATEST(0, BOM.qty_available - PRT.stock_level) ,
    PRT.stock_level = GREATEST(0, PRT.stock_level - (BOM.qty_planned ))
WHERE BOM.part_id = PRT.part_id
    AND BOM.po_number=9999999;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is to join in another version of the table.  This `JOIN` should use the primary key, which I'm guessing is `po_number`:

```
UPDATE mbom BOM JOIN
       parts PRT
       ON BOM.part_id = PRT.part_id LEFT JOIN
       mbom BOM2
       ON BOM.po_number = BOM2.po_number  -- just a guess that this is the primary key
    SET BOM.qty_planned = GREATEST(0, BOM.qty_planned - PRT.stock_level), 
        BOM.qty_available = GREATEST(0, BOM.qty_available - PRT.stock_level) ,
        PRT.stock_level = GREATEST(0, PRT.stock_level - (BOM2.qty_planned ))
    WHERE BOM.po_number = 9999999;
```

You should know that this "feature" of MySQL -- where the new value is referenced rather than the old one -- violates the SQL standard.  Most other databases would use the old value in your expression.

Comment: many thanks! works great. I guess this MySQL "feature" may be useful in some circumstances...

Comment: @MorSagmon . . . It would be if MySQL would really guarantee the order of evaluation of the `set`s.  However, the documentation says that they are usually evaluated in order, and that is not a guarantee.